# Is there a mouse trail option?

Tags: mouse

I have intermittent blindness in my right eye. Windows had a great mouse option that made a trail of cursors behind the one that's functional. It made my mouse easier to see. The control button helps me find my mouse, but I need something to help me track it as it moves.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

PS: I prefer bash shell installs, copy paste easier then having to read small download link on websites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by enabling **Show mouse** plugin from [**CompizConfig Settings manager**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/). If you don't have them already installed, you can install them via the  [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

After these have been installed, open **CompizConfig Settings manager** and enable **Show mouse** plugin. To initiate it use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> key combination.

I have the following settings in **General** tab and **Particle Options** which make the behaviour of the mouse approach of what you wish (maybe even better):

[image: ccsm - show mouse plugin - general tab]

[image: ccsm - show mouse pugin - particle option tab]

Comment: works perfectly what i did was made the radius small as posible, and the size of the sparks so its directly under my mouse. so its noticable but not distracting (the defaults were a bit much) thank you sooooo much now i dont have to spend time finding my cursor! (just another reason i wish MS-DOS had USB capibilities, so i could put it on my laptop when GUI not needed. my laptop has no PS\2) come to think of it GUI's dont really do me any good lol

Comment: oh and i had never heard of this program when i looked in the software center under disability software. its a great one it should be spotlighted

Comment: @Tarlug Compiz is compositing manager, therefor it's not listed as disability software, but has good capabilities to help :)

Comment: That is pretty awful I want simple trails, not a fireworks display following my mouse cursor! Wow. Interesting to learn about though. :O This doesn't really provide what the OP asked for.

Comment: i know that this was posted years ago but if you still don't want gui you can just quit xorg when not using it