# How to make the cursor have a trail on GNOME?

Tags: gnome, configuration, customization, cursor

I remember that in Windows one had the capability to make one's cursor have a trail, and there was a slider to indicate how long this trail would be. I believe that there was also something similar in the `unity-tweak-tool`, though I can't be absolutely certain of it.

Anyway, I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, I can't find anything to achieve my objective of giving my cursor a trail in the `gnome-control-center`, nor in the `gnome-tweak-tool`, so I was wondering how exactly I am going to manage to do it? I've done a search through `dconf-editor`, but I can't find anything, though that does not necessarily mean that it's not there because there are a lot of settings there...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a mouse trail option?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/370344/is-there-a-mouse-trail-option)

Comment: @Zacharee1 the "duplicate" is for Compiz. OP uses GNOME.

Comment: @A.B. I didn't think that mattered. I don't really know the difference.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Well, for starters I don't have Compiz installed...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda You're a little late :p

Comment: if it existed it should be in `org.gnome.desktop.a11y` schema. It seems that it is one of the thing deemed not useful... ;-|

Comment: @Rmano: Nope, not in there...

Comment: @Rmano The current celebratory site's them (with the mouse trails) made me revisit the search for the feature.  The feature is very useful.  I hope someone with programming experience might start to realize the facility.  I spend a lot of productive time looking for the mouse.  Every body's eyes loose efficiency with age.  The young programmers probably see it as an unneeded eye-candy, not as an accessibility tool... whereas the old fogies that would benefit don't think to ask for the crutch, and don't realize what they are missing.  If I find one I'll bring it back here.