# Anybody know of a way to active a cursor trail

Tags: cursor, mouse-pointer

There is a question and answer related to mouse trail option.  However, the OP appears to have needed something different ([Is there a mouse trail option?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370344/is-there-a-mouse-trail-option)).  His question was satisfied by turning on an elaborate `show mouse` feature.  In my question the mouse cursor is alright the way it is.  I'm familiar with compiz's `show mouse`.  There are also a number of features of displaying the way the mouse looks in Unity-tweak-tool and gnome-tweak-tool.

Most of the other Google search hits related to mouse trails are complaints of artifacts that are referred to as bugs.

The benefit of the trail over just showing the location of the mouse, is that the trail appears when the mouse moves.  This will facilitate my finding the mouse in my three monitor work setup.  Having the mouse always showing as in the particle display all the time would be distracting.

It should get activated when mouse is moving deactivated when there is no motion.

I've seen some references to CCSM's extra plugins such as in this video: [Mouse Cursor Trails - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCfq7iozzi0).  I have installed a number of the plugins, but have yet to find one for CCSM.

Is there any apps or addon? hopefully someone will be familiar with it.

Comment: Yes, there was a mouse trail feature in earlier compiz. But sinced Ubuntu started using Unity, many of the plugins are dropped from compiz. One of them is mouse trail option. I don't know if you can compile it yourself now