# How to use mouse trails like Windows without Compiz?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, kde, cursor

[image]
 <sub>Mouse trails in Windows</sub>

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/370344/124466) question, but it is about Compiz, which is not actively developed anymore.

How to use mouse trails in recent versions Ubuntu (let's say, 22.04 LTS)?

I am looking for answers for both GNOME and KDE, and something which preferably work in both X.Org and Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

**For GNOME (Ubuntu):**

Install and use the xinput command-line tool by running the following command:

`sudo apt install xinput`

Use the xinput command to enable mouse trails. Open a terminal and run the following command to list the available input devices:

`xinput list`

Identify the ID of your mouse device in the list.

Run the following command, replacing  with the ID of your mouse device:

`xinput set-prop <device-id> 'libinput Pointer Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1`

This command disables the default pointer acceleration and enables a custom profile that creates the mouse trail effect. You may need to experiment with different values to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Hmm, according to `xinput list-props`, neither my `Virtual core pointer` nor my `TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint` have that property.